# Compact solution for low voltage AC generation from switching power supply

Tags: power, ac

I have an app which will have a pretty standard flyback switched mode power supply, the design is yet to be chosen but it will be isolated ~6W output, with standard mains input. For example, say something like STEVAL-ISA004V1 or for example TEA172x based solution.

The app will have logic and MCU so 5V and 3.3V will be part of the output, and transformer will have multiple taps.

My question is, whats a good compact way of generating fixed frequency 50/60hz low voltage AC from there, like 16VAC at 0.1A ? Doesnt need to be perfect sinusoidal but close enough.

The obvious way would be to have about 32V DC rectified and then do H-bridge inverter, with the MCU spare PWM channel doing DDS generation of the waveform.

Btw i guess if the load is rated "16VAC" then the DC voltage before inverter has to be 2x16, i.e. thats peak to peak, not RMS? 
All the inverter designs i'm finding are for 110V/230V, nothing low voltage, so i guess the best bet is using integrated H-bridges designed for small brushless DC motor drives.

Comment: Have you tried combining PWM sinusoidal generation with a PWM-based booster (which makes it, yes, PWM-modulated PWM)?

Comment: Please provide a link to a 110V/230V o/p design and maybe someone can recommend how to alter it.

Comment: Link to STEVAL-ISA004V1 

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/STEVAL-ISA004V1/497-5864-ND/1534379

TEA172x solution ( lower power, but can be changed )
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TEA1721ADB1061/TEA1721ADB1061-ND/4302021